# Get quill JS HTML into a C# Variable

Tags: javascript, c#, quill

I am trying to implement a QUILL.JS WYSIWYG editor in my webpage. I do not know how to get the HTML From the Editor into a usable variable that I can store in my database.

ASPX

```
<div id="quill-editor"></div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1"  CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server"  OnClientClick="returnString();" Text="Ssubmit" onclick="Button1_Click" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnResultValue" Value="0" runat="server" />
```

JS On ASPX

```
                <script>
                    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
                        if (!window.Quill) {
                            return $('#quill-editor,#quill-toolbar,#quill-bubble-editor,#quill-bubble-toolbar').remove();
                        }
                        var editor = new Quill('#quill-editor', {
                            modules: {
                                toolbar: '#quill-toolbar'
                            },
                            placeholder: 'Type something',
                            theme: 'snow'
                        });                              
                  </script>
```

How do i store the HTML Output into the Hidden Field, so that I can retrieve it in my code behind?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the ClientIDMode="Static" in your hidden field

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnResultValue" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

then from jquery:

```
$("#hdnResultValue").val("test");
```

By enabeling CliendIdMode static, you will be able to access that field by id. Other wise you have to use below way, since client id of asp tags is generated one.

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('<%= hdnResultValue.ClientID %>');
```

From code behind

```
hdnResultValue.Value.ToString();
```